# Grammar about infinitive

Tags: grammar

I sometimes see people using the infinitive of a verb after "is" without "to".Like the following:

> what he did is tell others the story.

(1)Is it grammatically correct?
(2)Also, is it valid to  add a "to" before tell ?
and (3) is it valid to use gerund "telling",will it sound confusing with present continuous tense then?

Comment: Yes, it's fine. Infinitival clauses can occur as predicative complement. Yes, you can add "to". No, you can't use a gerund-participial (_-ing_) clause as complement in your particular example.

Comment: @BillJ  If i add "to", will it alter the meaning? And which sounds more natural to native speaker of English, with or without to?thanks.

Comment: No, there would be no change of meaning. Both are perfectly natural; personally I would add "to", but it is a free choice.

Comment: @BillJ Infinitive clause without to cannot be used at the beginning of a sentence? In this case, we have to use gerund or “to” at the beginning, right?

Comment: Infinitival clauses at the beginning such as subject require "to". Imperative clauses like "Wash your hands!" do not.

Answer (score 1):

Adding "to" before a verb is optional. If it sounds natural enough without it to you, then it isn't needed. However, unrelated to your question, it should be "was" not "is" since "did" is in the past tense.